# Load annotated spring bean from Jar

Tags: spring, spring-3, spring-annotations

If the spring bean used annotation in jar file, how can I load mythe bean instance in my class?

In jar file

```
package org.java.service.test;

@Service(value = "MyService")
public class MyService {

    @Resource(name = "myproperties")
    private Properties properties;
}
```

In my project

```
package org.java.project.test;

@Service(value = "OtherService")
public class OtherService {
    @Resource(name = "MyService")
    private MyService myService;
}
```

In spring-beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ....>

    <context:annotation-config/>    
    <context:component-scan base-package=org.java.service.test, org.java.project.test"/>
    .....
</beans>
```

I also try as below, it does not work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ....>

    <context:annotation-config/>    
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.java.service.test"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.java.project.test"/>
    .....
</beans>
```

Comment: What server container are you using, how are packaging the jar, where are you putting the jar?

Comment: Can you give the exception trace?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue ? I am facing a similar one

Comment: found solution?, please share if yes...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in your component-scan configuration.
Rather than using `@Resource` annotation on your field `private MyService myService;` you shoudl use `@Autowired` annotation.

So now your code in class OtherService will be like below:

```
package org.java.project.test; 

@Service(value = "OtherService") 
public class OtherService { 
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService; 
}
```

According to me that should work for you. Just try it. Cheers.

Comment: `@Resource` acts almost like `@Autowired` so I don't think it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although I try to use @Autowired annotation, I cannot load bean instance.

Answer (score 0):

**`<context:component-scan>`** 
scans those packages which are in the current project.

Comment: Did you check my question? I post two classes, one from project, another from jar file. **In jar file** and **In my project**. You cannot say **those packages which are in the current project**